# Is there new easy to use methods for bidimensional density estimation?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Recently, I was learning about density estimation with non-parametric methods, brilliantly [detailed here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html) by Jake VanderPlas. I'm just a beginner in the area, and I also heard about mixture models. I realized that KDE and GMM are well known to the public in two-dimensional (often spatial) analysis, but, as far as I know, these are relatively old methods.

Is there a new method for estimating two-dimensional density based on deep learning or another new technique that can be easily used to compare with KDE? For example, I was wondering if there is any method that has bandwidth and kernel varying over the data range.